# How to set positive, negative and neutral colors and icons in Angular on data from an api

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set my data from an API to look like the way it appears on the stock market
[image]

Positive number turn to green plus the icon, negative to turn to red and the down icon and the neutral to be a shade of yellow with the up and down icon. I tried using a list but it doesn't work right have tried using a table still the same output.  How can I achieve this?

What I have done so far using a table

```html
                      <table class="table" id="htmlData">
                          <thead class="thead">
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="list-group">

                          <tr class="list-group-item">
                            <td
                              style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; font-size: 2em;font-weight: bold;color:white">
                              UMME
                            </td>
                            <td
                              style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; font-size: 2em;font-weight: bold;color:white">{{report.umme | number : '1.2-2'}}
                              %
                            </td>
                            <td class="warning"
                                style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; font-size: 2em;font-weight: bold;color:white"
                                [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : (report.umme_daily_change > 0) ? 'green': 'red' }">
                              {{report.umme_daily_change | number : '1.4-4'}}</td>
                            <td
                              style="vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; font-size: 2em;font-weight: bold;color:white"
                              [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : (report.umme_daily_change > 0) ? getIncrease():  getDecrease() }"
                              style="background-repeat: no-repeat"></td>
                          </tr>
                          

                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract all three color styles to css and use conditional on css classes

```
<td
 [class.colorRed]="umme_daily_change < 0"
 [class.colorNeutral] = "umme_daily_change === 0"
 [class.colorPositive] = "umme_daily_change > 0
></td>
```

---

```
.colorRed{
  background-color: red;
}
.colorNeutral{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.colorPositive{
  background-color: green;
}
```

With that syntax the class that fulfills the following condition is set on the html element.

Comment: HI @Michael and the icons?

Comment: @arriff are the icons css (like in font awesome) too?

Comment: HI @Michael, no they are images

Comment: <img *ngIf="condition">